# How to code multithreaded TCP/IP sender

Tags: multithreading, tcp

I need a TCP/IP sender that will throw the contents of a text file as a byte stream to a configurable set of IP and ports. Preferably something that can be contained in just one thread and configurable for several destinations. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coming up with your own sending mechanism, consider using message queues. They are very easy to use and most have excellent performance(e.g. [zeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) can send 4.7 million messages per second for a 64 byte message)